# How to flatten a data frame in Python in which one column contains a json object?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which is one of the column is a json object as shown below

```
customer_id |    date    |             json_object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A101        | 2022-06-21 | {'name':['james'],'age':[55], 'hobby':['pubg']}
A102        | 2022-06-22 | {'name':['tarzan'],'status':[]}
```

The content of the jason object is not uniform. In the above example, the json object in the first row as 'hobby' which is not present in the json object of the second row. Similary in the 2nd row, the attribute status is empty i.e. []

**Question**: How can I flatten this dataframe in Python to create a new dataframe where each row corresponds to one json object only as shown below

```
customer_id |    date    | attribute
---------------------------------------------
A101        | 2022-06-21 | 'name': 'james'
A101        | 2022-06-21 | 'age': 55
A101        | 2022-06-21 | 'hobby': 'pubg'
A102        | 2022-06-22 | 'name': 'tarzan'
A102        | 2022-06-22 | 'status':
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each value of `json_object` is a `dict`, you could also use the following approach:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        "customer_id": ["A101", "A102"],
        "date": ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-22"],
        "json_object": [{'name': 'james','age':55, 'hobby':'pubg'}, {'name': 'tarzan','status':'single'}]
    }
)
df["json_object"] = df["json_object"].map(lambda x: [[i, x[i]] for i in x])
df = df.explode(column="json_object")
df.json_object = df.json_object.str[0].astype(str) + ": " + df.json_object.str[1].astype(str) 
df

------------------------------------------
    customer_id  date        json_object
0   A101         2022-06-21  name: james
0   A101         2022-06-21  age: 55
0   A101         2022-06-21  hobby: pubg
1   A102         2022-06-22  name: tarzan
1   A102         2022-06-22  status: single
------------------------------------------
```

---

#### EDIT

Since you changed your data frame to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        "customer_id": ["A101", "A102"],
        "date": ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-22"],
        "json_object": [{'name': ['james'],'age':[55], 'hobby':['pubg']}, {'name': ['tarzan'],'status':['single']}]
    }
)
```

my code must be adjusted as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        "customer_id": ["A101", "A102"],
        "date": ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-22"],
        "json_object": [{'name': ['james'],'age':[55], 'hobby':['pubg']}, {'name': ['tarzan'],'status':['single']}]
    }
)
df["json_object"] = df["json_object"].map(lambda x: [[i, x[i][0]] for i in x])
df = df.explode(column="json_object")
df.json_object = df.json_object.str[0].astype(str) + ": " + df.json_object.str[1].astype(str) 
df
```

If empty lists are included then simply add an `if-else` condition inside the `lambda` function. Note, I have also renamed the columns in the next code extraction.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        "customer_id": ["A101", "A102"],
        "date": ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-22"],
        "json_object": [{'name': ['james'],'age':[55], 'hobby':['pubg']}, {'name': ['tarzan'],'status':[]}]
    }
)
df["json_object"] = df["json_object"].map(lambda x: [[i, x[i][0]] if x[i] else [i, ""] for i in x])
df = df.rename(columns={"json_object": "attribute"}).explode(column="attribute")
df.attribute = df.attribute.str[0].astype(str) + ": " + df.attribute.str[1].astype(str)
```

Comment: With this example data it work. But on running this code on the larger data of 5000 rows, it throws an error saying 'string indices must be integers'. Any idea why so? Is because some attributes have empty values e.g. 'name':[]. Apologies but I have updated the example data accordingly in the question

Comment: @Stacker, I don't thinks that is the reason for the error. It would have thrown something like `list index out of range` if the empy list was the reason. Anyway, I updated my code to handle empty lists. Can you provide more information? It is hard to debug with so little information.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it and your code works. Accepting your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you right:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["json_object"] = df["json_object"].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x).items())
df = df.explode("json_object")
```

After this the `df` will be:

```
  customer_id        date       json_object
0        A101  2022-06-21     (name, james)
0        A101  2022-06-21         (age, 55)
0        A101  2022-06-21     (hobby, pubg)
1        A102  2022-06-22    (name, tarzan)
1        A102  2022-06-22  (status, single)
```

Then:

```py
df["attribute"] = df["json_object"].apply(lambda x: "{}: {}".format(*x))
df = df.drop(columns="json_object")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  customer_id        date       attribute
0        A101  2022-06-21     name: james
0        A101  2022-06-21         age: 55
0        A101  2022-06-21     hobby: pubg
1        A102  2022-06-22    name: tarzan
1        A102  2022-06-22  status: single
```

Comment: When I try this, I am getting an error. after the explode step, instead of getting one row each for name, age and hobby, I am getting all of them in a single row as ((name,james),(age,55), hobby,pubg). Basically it is still in a single row. Is it because in my original data, the the values of the attributes are inside square brackets as shown in the updated question's dataframe

Answer (score 2):

This is not the data structure you asked for and it depends on your subsequent steps, but it is generally a good idea to put one value into one cell and don't mix different data in a single column. So with the data

```py
data = {"customer_id": "A101 A102".split(), 
        "date": "2022-06-21 2022-06-22".split(), 
        "json_object": [{'name':['james'], 'age':[55], 'hobby':['pubg']}, {'name':['tarzan'],'status':[]}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

and the df

```
  customer_id        date                                        json_object
0        A101  2022-06-21  {'name': ['james'], 'age': [55], 'hobby': ['pu...
1        A102  2022-06-22                 {'name': ['tarzan'], 'status': []}
```

you could also do something like

```py
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.json_object)], axis=1).drop("json_object", axis=1)
```

which will give you the data in separate columns, (almost) ready for further processing.

```
  customer_id        date      name   age   hobby status
0        A101  2022-06-21   [james]  [55]  [pubg]    NaN
1        A102  2022-06-22  [tarzan]   NaN     NaN     []
```